# How can we convert binary number into its octal number using c#?

Tags: c#

****Hey i was working on an application which converts any basenumber like (2,8,10,16,etc) to user's desire base system. I am having a problem in converting a binary number to its octal number can anyone help me out?

I tried everthing like

```
// i am taking a binary number in value and then converting it to base 8

Int32 value = int.Parse(convertnumber);                           
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(value, 8));
```

For example:
value =10011

Answer should be this  "23"  but using the above code i am getting "23433"

Comment: Have you tried `Console.WriteLine(value)` to see the actual value of the number?  In other words: I think your code is correct, but the value is different from what you think it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string binary = "10011";
int integer = Convert.ToInt32(binary, 2);
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(integer, 8));

Output: 23
```

In this example we convert the binary string representation to an integer and from an integer to the octal string representation.

Comment: cant we directly convert binary to octal system ?

Comment: @Simucal, @Pro_Zeck: This answer doesn’t convert anything to decimal at all.

Comment: @Timwi, how does it not?  From base 2 (binary) to base 10 (decimal) then from base 10 to base 8 (octal).

Comment: @Simucal: Your code (correctly) converts from the binary string representation to an integer and then from the integer to the octal string representation. There is absolutely no base-10 representation anywhere in this process.

Comment: @Simucal the integer is just an integer. Only a _representation_ of an integer can have a base. Like, when you write it down as a series of digits. Or, when you store it in transistors or capacitors as a series of bits. But semantically, a value stored in C#'s "int" type has *no base* at all.

Comment: @Timwi, I see what you are saying now.  I'll make a correction.

Answer (score 5):

"23433" is is the correct answer, when converting "10011" in base 10 to base 8.

You may have meant to interpret "10011" as a binary number.  In which case, you want:

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(convertnumber, 2);
```

**Edit**: in response to comments, here's almost-complete code:

```
string val = "10011";
int convertnumber = Convert.ToInt32(val, 2);
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(convertnumber, 8)); // prints "23"
```

Comment: i want 10011 binary number Converted to base 8 number

Comment: @Pro_Zeck: I got that. Does my answer not help? You want to read in the string into an integer variable, interpreting that string as a base-2 number, as I've demonstrated above. Then, you want the representation of that integer as base 8, as you've got in your last line of code.

Comment: @SIMUCAL code is working perfectly. still i dont know why we have to first convert binary to decimal and then decimal to octal.

Comment: why acn we just convert binary to octal directly there must be a way ?

Comment: @Pro_Zeck: can you elaborate? The code I'm using in my question (see my edit, with an almost-complete program) prints "23".

Comment: @Pro_Zeck: there's no way to convert in one statement, AFAIK. You could write a method for it, I suppose (`ConvertIntegerBase(string val, int baseIn, int baseOut);`). Why do you need to do it in one line?

Comment: dude now what you wrote is correct beacuse in your first comment program you were converting binary to decimal. But i was asking for binary to octal ... What you wrote now its correct .

Comment: @Pro_Zeck: you didn't read closely enough. I was describing what you **were** doing, then I described what you **should** be doing.

Comment: i wannted that in one statement because i wanted to increase the efficiency and the execution of the program must faster ! Suppose if i were making a appliction in which a text file is uploaded containing 1 thousand or more binary to octal base that would take long time to solve it.

Comment: @Pro_Zeck: ah, I see. Important thing to learn: fewer lines of code does not always mean faster execution. If you want a detailed lesson in this, go grab Reflector, and walk through the call stack for the `Int32.Parse` method. That simple little one-line chunk of code does so much, your head will spin.

Comment: @Pro_Zeck: there's no reasonable way to convert bases without having an integer to work with first. Thus, you need to convert your string (which is not a number, not as far as .NET's concerned) to an integer (using base-2 representation), then convert that integer to a string (using base-8 representation).

Answer (score 3):

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(convertnumber, 2);
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(value, 8));
```

You are taking a base 10 number 10011 and converting it to base 8. Which is 23433.

Comment: Why are you calling this “convert to decimal”? There is no conversion to decimal anywhere.

Comment: @Timwi: The decimal numeral system (also called base ten or occasionally denary) has ten as its base

Comment: @Yuriy: No, really? You don’t say! There’s still no decimal anywhere in your code though. (And of course there shouldn’t be. The code is correct. The comment is wrong.)

Comment: @Timwi `int` is in base 10, aka decimal

Comment: @Yuriy: LOL, no it isn’t... has never been. Where did you get that from?

Comment: @Timwi ok, what base do you think `int` is in?

Comment: @Yuriy: **int is not a string of digits.** An `int` is not a sequence of characters. It is *the number itself*. It is not in any base. (Of course physically it is stored in memory as *binary*, but that’s irrelevant.)

Comment: @Yuriy I strongly recommend that you ask "What base is `int` in?" as a separate question, here on SO, then you can get much more detailed answers.

Comment: @romkyns: No reason, I agree with him. The value is stored in binary. By default the representation of it is base 10. Thats the reason why I say it is decimal. If you want to argue semantics, that I never displayed it, so it was never base 10,  you're possibly right. I'll take down the comment since I've also seemed to confuse myself.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this manually (so you understand what is going on) here is a suggestion:

First pad the binary string to be divisable by 3 ( 3 bits = 1 octal digit )

```
string binary = "10011";
int pad = binary.Length % 3;
binary = new string('0', 3-pad) + binary;
```

Then process each three bits into one octal digit

```
int n = binary.Length / 3;
char[] bin_digits = binary.ToCharArray();
char[] oct_digits = new char[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    int digit = bin_digits.Skip(3 * i).Take(3).Aggregate(0,
        (x, v) => (int)v - (int)'0' + 2 * x);
    // x is the value accumulation
    // v is a char '0' or '1' representing a bit and is converted to int 0, 1
    oct_digits[i] = (char)(digit + (int)'0');
    // convert int to char digit
}
```

Convert the digits array into a string

```
string oct_value = new string(oct_digits);
```

Example results:
`"10011"   -> "23"`
`"11000"   -> "30"` 
`"1011011" -> "133"`

Comment: this really hepled alot ! now i can easily work on this widout using c# builtin libraries

Answer (score 1):

Naturally, `int.Parse` parses a *decimal* number. If your input is binary, then you'll need to first do a conversion from binary to integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Int32 value = Convert.ToInt32( "10011", 2 );
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(value, 8));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because int.Parse is converting 10011 to, well, 10011 in decimal. It is not converting it from 10011 binary to 23 octal (19 decimal) as you want it to.

Comment: In octal (base 8), it's 23, not 19.  The OP asked for binary to octal conversion.