# Why is '\117' a valid character literal in Java?

Tags: java, character, special-characters

I've seen this `char` defined as
`char ch = '\117'`

**What kind of representation** is `'\117'` in?

I know `escaped-sequence` is `'\n'`, for instance, or `unicode` is `` `\udddd' ``, where `d` is a single hex digit, but I've never seen such thing as `'\117'` in my entire life!
Surprisingly, it does compile! (And the output is `O`)

Comment: See [Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6).

Comment: This is octal notation. See [Why do Java octal escapes only go up to 255?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9543026/111424), especially [rob mayoff's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9543611/111424). It's probably for compatibility with older languages and programmers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the octal representation for ascii.  You can see lots more values of it here: http://donsnotes.com/tech/charsets/ascii.html

Answer (score 8):

It's in octal, a holdover from C/C++.

Answer (score 3):

That is because its the Octal representation of captial **O** character.

If you try to print your `char ch='\117';` , you will see that it prints `O`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a Octal value for character "O", when I did system.out.println(..) I got this output:

```
char ch = '\117';
System.out.println("Char is: " + ch);
```

Output:

```
Char is : O
```

Comment: It's more than that, it's an ASCII value in octal.

Comment: Sorry, updated same :) @EJP