# What are the Java semantics of an escaped number in a character literal, e.g. '\15' ?

Tags: java, syntax, character, literals, octal

Please explain what, exactly, happens when the following sections of code are executed:

```
int a='\15';
System.out.println(a);
```

this prints out 13;

```
int a='\25';
System.out.println(a);
```

this prints out 21;

```
int a='\100';
System.out.println(a);
```

this prints out 64.

Comment: Looks like it is interpreting the number as an octal.

Comment: `int a='\15'` first creates a `char` based on octal number "15" (decimal 13, as a char, it's the ascii "Carriage Return"), which you then recast to an `int` integer. This is legal since chars are 16 bit integers, so it's a safe upcast and no notices about casting are issued by Java. The other answers cover the whole octal/decimal thing already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is '\117' a valid character literal in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950593/why-is-117-a-valid-character-literal-in-java)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You have assigned a character literal, which is delimited by single quotes, eg `'a'` (as distinct from a String literal, which is delimited by double quotes, eg `"a"`) to an `int` variable. Java does an automatic widening cast from the 16-bit unsigned `char` to the 32-bit signed `int`.

However, when a character literal is a backslash followed by 1-3 digits, it is an [*octal*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) ([base/radix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix) 8) representation of the character. Thus:

- `\15` = 1×8 + 5 = 13 (a carriage return; same as `'\r'`)
- `\25` = 2×8 + 5 = 21 (a NAK char - negative acknowledgement)
- `\100` = 1×64 + 0×8 + 0 = 64 (the @ symbol; same as `'@'`)

For more info on character literals and escape sequences, see JLS sections:

- [3.10.4: Character Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.4)
- [3.10.6: Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6)

Quoting the [BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) from 3.10.6:

```
OctalEscape:
    \ OctalDigit
    \ OctalDigit OctalDigit
    \ ZeroToThree OctalDigit OctalDigit

OctalDigit: one of
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

ZeroToThree: one of
    0 1 2 3
```

Comment: I can't find it in section 3.10.1.. It's in 3.10.4, Character Literals

Comment: The section on integer literals is irrelevant. See [Section 3.10.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.4). Also see [Section 3.10.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) for character and string escape sequences.

Comment: `1-3 digits` -- it should have been `0-3`. And its for 3 digit octal, two digit octal can still have from `0-7`. ex. '\77' is still valid.

Comment: @Jayamohan I meant 1-3 in quantity, not value

Comment: @Bohemian. Nice answer. I'd suggest you add the syntax of octal escape literal here, so it will be more clear. :)

Comment: @RohitJain Thanks. You're pretty good at encyclopaedic answers and references - is that edit what you meant?

Comment: @Bohemian. hehe :) Not exactly. I believe answer containing words from official source is far better than answer just containing your own words. But it should be a mixture of both. Yes, that is what exactly I meant. :)

Comment: SO, it needs to be 100 ha! :) OK... +1, btw, nice answer

Answer (score 19):

The notation `\nnn` denotes an octal character code in Java.  so `int a = '\15'` assigns the auto-cast'ed value of octal character 15 to `a` which is decimal 13.

Comment: The notation `\nnn` does _not_ denote an octal number in Java. In OP's code, it denotes an octal character escape sequence. The surrounding quote marks are essential. The character is then widened to an integer value by the assignment. (Octal numbers are denoted by a leading zero digit.)

Comment: Good point; should have mentioned the auto-cast in the answer.  Updated the answer.

Answer (score 6):

The fact that you put the digits in quotes makes me suspect it is interpreting the number as a character literal. The digits that follow must be in octal.