# Understanding output of printf containing backslash (\012)

Tags: c, string, printf

Can you please help me to understand the output of this simple code:

```
const char str[10] = "55\01234";
printf("%s", str);
```

The output is:

```
55
34
```

Comment: Just interested in why someone downvoted this ^^

Comment: It's also worth noting that it is because you provided a string in double-quotes that it was interpreted this way. Because if you had added it one character at a time, you would have had to choose between `'\\', '0', '1', '2'`, `'\0', '1', '2'`, `'\012'` (which also happen to change the size of the char table).

Comment: That's one of those fun little facts about C that are not well known. The same way if you write an integer starting with a `0`, it is automatically interpreted as octal. `int i = 012;` is the same as `int i = 10;` or `printf("%d\n", 012);` outputs `10`.

Comment: SSDD: the [Java version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108008/what-are-the-java-semantics-of-an-escaped-number-in-a-character-literal-e-g)

Comment: @Tonio if it's not widely known then I wonder how in the world people are learning C, since things like the formats of literals are usually covered in the introductory material before you even get to *statements*.

Comment: @hobbs From what I could see, very few C programming courses talk about octals in general... And to be honest, it's not overly useful, why would anyone want to write `012` instead of `10` or `\012` instead of `\n`? And I know you can probably dig up an example where it's useful, but in general?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The character sequence `\012` inside the string is interpreted as an [octal escape sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences). The value `012` interpreted as octal is `10` in decimal, which is the line feed (`\n`) character on most terminals.

From the Wikipedia page:

> An octal escape sequence consists of `\` followed by one, two, or three octal digits. The octal escape sequence ends when it either contains three octal digits already, or the next character is not an octal digit.

Since your sequence contains three valid octal digits, that's how it's going to be parsed. It doesn't continue with the `3` from `34`, since that would be a fourth digit and only three digits are supported.

So you could write your string as `"55\n34"`, which is more clearly what you're seeing and which would be more portable since it's no longer hard-coding the newline but instead letting the compiler generate something suitable.

Comment: Can you also add why it takes **12** as the octal number, and not **1** or **123**?

Comment: @Zaibis What? The page also says "Note that some three-digit octal escape sequences may be too large to fit in a single character; this results in an implementation-defined value for the character actually produced." which might be relevant for `\777` if that's what you're talking about (777 octal is 511 decimal, which is out of range for 8-bit character encodings).

Answer (score 17):

`\012` is an [escape sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C) which represents *`octal`* code of symbol:

```
012 = 10 = 0xa = LINE FEED (in ASCII)
```

So your string looks like `55[LINE FEED]34`.

`LINE FEED` character is interpreted as [newline sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) on many platforms. That is why you see two strings on a terminal.

Comment: Under which specification that is given?

Comment: I never stumbled over this before, but it is in the c99 ISO/IEC:9899 If you want it to add: it can be found under 6.4.4.4 Character constants point 3 and point 9 gives restriction to the values.

Comment: @Zaibis: thanks for the notes. I'm not sure quoting standard will make my answer more clear to OP. I'd prefer to keep wikipedia link.

Comment: I'm fine with that too. But the wiki link isn't 100% accurate by saying `\nnn` will take `n` as octal values (as point 9 states). I posted it that for as own answer. Not expecting to get the expected one.

Comment: Does it specify when an escape sequence must end? I remember once mistakenly thinking `\x` escape sequences to have a fixed length of 2, only to get an error "invalid escape sequence" in Visual Studio for, say, `"A\xBCD"`. Just reproduced it, VS2005 says `error C2022: '3021' : too big for character` But for the question's sequence, it says `warning C4125: decimal digit terminates octal escape sequence`, meaning it could be more standardized than hex sequences.

Comment: @Medionic: this is as I stated what is incorrect on wiki. point 9 states (as you can see in my answer) the escape sequence is limited to be a value fitting into range of unsigned char. what would be for hex limited to `\xFF` and for octal: `\377`

Comment: @Medionic: octal sequences can have 1, 2 or 3 digits according to a grammar: http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.4.4.4.html

Comment: @Medinoc Detail: Hexadecimal sequences have no length limit.  Octal escape sequences are limited up to 3.  If the value exceeds the `unsigned char` range the result is an implementation-defined value.

Comment: @Zaibis "the escape sequence is limited to be a value fitting into range of unsigned char. what would be for hex limited to \xFF and for octal: \377" is not so. "Each octal or hexadecimal escape sequence is the longest sequence of characters that can constitute the escape sequence."  §6.4.4.4 7  which is max 3 for octal and unlimited for hexadecimal.  The result of values outside the `unsigned char` range is implementation-defined, but the escape sequence itself is not so limited.

Answer (score 6):

`\012` is a new line escape sequence as others stated already.
(What might be, as chux absolute correct commented, different if ASCII isn't the used charset. But anyway it is in this notation an octal digit.)

this is meant by standard as it says for c99 in ISO/IEC 9899

for:

> 6.4.4.4 Character constants

[...]

> 3 The single-quote ', the double-quote ", the question-mark ?, the backslash \, and
>   arbitrary integer values are representable according to the following table of escape
>   sequences:
>
> single quote' \'
>
> double quote" \"
>
> question mark? \?
>
> backslash\ \
>
> octal character \octal digits
>
> hexadecimal character \x hexadecimal digits

And the range it gets bound to:

> Constraints
>
> 9 The value of an octal or hexadecimal escape sequence shall be in the range of
>   representable values for the type unsigned char for an integer character constant, or
>   the unsigned type corresponding to wchar_t for a wide character constant.

Comment: "`\012` is a new line escape sequence" is true when using ASCII, so its 99.9+% of the time correct, but this is not per the C spec.

Comment: @chux: I totally agree, sorry for my incorrectness, I will fix that as soon I can find the time for edit.