# Octal representation of characters in java

Tags: java, character-encoding, char

I write the code `System.out.println('\577');` and it produces unclosed character literal error. What's the problem here as all the digits are in the limits of the octal integers?

Comment: What _char_ is `\577` supposed to be?

Comment: You need to escape back slash,   System.out.println("\\577");

Comment: Not sure if this still applies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543026/why-do-java-octal-escapes-only-go-up-to-255 but base on that octal only go up to 255.

Comment: Your octal is too large. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543026/why-do-java-octal-escapes-only-go-up-to-255

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do Java octal escapes only go up to 255?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543026/why-do-java-octal-escapes-only-go-up-to-255)

Comment: @KevinNg thanks...This solved

Comment: @user12208242 - You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Just change it to `System.out.println("/577");`. You are getting error because you are using `' '` for a **String** but single quot (' ') can't take more that a **Character**, So you need to use `" "` (double quot) when you take into more than one character or string. Hope it works.